# osgi blueprint catch event update

Tags: osgi, blueprint-osgi

i want to execute script when my bundle is update, uninstall, or new.

I use actualy destroy-method and init-method but i don't now if my bundle has just "stop" or "remove".

```
 <bean id="plugin" class="com.toto.OrderPlugin" destroy-method="remove" init-method="install">
```

for Sample, why i want to catch event
When my bundle is update :

1. i want to know old version and new version and execute script in condition
   if my bundle is uninstall :
2. i want to drop datable
   if my bundle is new
3. i want to create datable

What is the right way to do this type of process? Can you give me an example?

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in that case I'd go for a std. Activator. Skip using the blueprint xml and use a Bundle-Activator instead, this way you have full control about your bundle start behaviour.

Comment: Thank you Achim, I can do with BundleActivator but I'd like to do the same process with blueprint, there is no way to make it with blueprint. Blueprint does not know the status of the bundle?

Comment: well the time the blueprint extender kicks in, the bundle is already Active :-)
You might try with a init and destroy method, that might work also. For init it's called: init-method

Comment: But the problem with init-method, i don't know if my bundle is install or simply activate.i want to know also if update to check old and new version.

Comment: that's the main issue here, you just don't get a hold on it using Blueprint, and actually with the activator neither. The Activator is used when the Bundle is going from resolved to Active, at this point you just don't know if your bundle actually is updated or just plain started after a stop. You probably need something like a special Bundle tracker, that does it for you. In that case you might find the information. The bundle itself doesn't know what happend to it :-)

Comment: Ok, so i resume. It is not possible to do this with blueprint in native. I must create a bundle tracker and catch event. PS: And the version 3.0.0 pax, release??? ?
Thanks Achim ;-)